# Use spring datasource of maven application within its dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm planning to build a library using spring and use it as an mvn dependency. The library would be used as an api in several projects. The api does only database operations. Can the included dependency get the datasource/jdbcTemplate of the project it is included in as an Autowired spring bean?

the datasource/jdbctemplate that we use in the spring application context is like following

```
<bean id="JdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as there is a been with the name datasource and class javax.sql.DataSource. It needs to be available either through configuration, XML wiring or component scanning.

If creating a new library API it would be good to document what the user needs to make available for wiring.

Comment: The jar which I created did not even require the context file. I followed the folder structure similar to the project where it will be included in, the component scan of the parent project took care of loading the beans of this for me.